# how can i implement count down timer in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, timer

I want to show a count down timer in my view. I have a `duration` column, in my table `assessments` which stores `integer` value.

This value is in minutes. I want to pass these minutes to a count-down-timer. so that it will start count down from what ever the value I sent to till zero.

for example if I send 60 minutes, then I want the timer to start from `59 minutes : 59 seconds` and should stop at  `00 minutes: 00 seconds` how can I implement this?

I tried implementing this with `countdown` gem but its not working. seams the gem is in active from very long time. Is there any up to dated gem to implement this?

I tried using a [jquery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Extremely-Lightweight-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-downCount/).

Here for the date option I want to send my rails view variable to this plugin but do not know how can I do that please help me on this.

Comment: Ruby is very bad at handling threads,  for sure best option is to use js

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show in a browser then use JavaScript.

This is just for Ruby version.

```
def timer(t)
    s = t * 60
    while s > 0
       s -= 1
       sleep 1
       seconds = s % 60
       minutes = (s / 60) % 60
       # hours = s / (60 * 60)
       puts format("%02d minutes: %02d seconds ", minutes, seconds)
    end
end

t = 60
timer(t)
```

Comment: mmm sorry do you understand that whole process will be on hold until executed?